# Filter data array on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-xarray

From xarray's tutorial data, I want to extract a `DataArray` that contains number of warm days in month, defined as between 22 and 30 Celcius:

```
airtemps = xr.tutorial.load_dataset('air_temperature')
airtemps = airtemps.sel(time=slice('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31'))
airtemps['air'] = airtemps.air - 273.15

air_day = airtemps.resample('1D', 'time', how='mean')
# Define multiple conditions - How can this be done programatically?
```

I am now looking for a way to create this map below programmatically, also being able to add more conditions

```
meets_condition = (air_day.air > 22) & (air_day.air < 30)
warm_days = meets_condition.resample('M', dim='time', how='sum')
```

Conditions could be defined like so:

```
not_cold = ('air',  operator.ge, 22)
not_hot  = ('air',  operator.le, 30)
```

I can do this simply with one condition:

```
variable, operator_fn, value = not_cold
meets_condition = operator_fn(air_day[variable], value)
warm_but_possibly_hot_days = meets_condition.resample('M', dim='time', how='sum')
```

But I'm struggeling adding multiple, dynamically. I can do this

```
comfy_warm = [not_cold, not_hot]

all_maps = [fn(air_day[var], val) for var, fn, val in comfy_warm]
(all_maps[0] & all_maps[1]).resample('M', dim='time', how='sum')
```

But I'm looking to do sth. like this

```
np.all(all_maps).resample('M', dim='time', how='sum')
```

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/TomTom101/25e0e76f11a5da57523a60fb280005c1) for convenience. As always, I am thankful in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
xr.ufuncs.logical_and.reduce(all_maps)
```

It applies the `and` operation element-wise across all the boolean arrays of the same length, and produces one result of that same length.  Of course you can use `logical_or` or any other suitable [ufunc](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/api.html#universal-functions).

Comment: I already tried this, but it a) takes forever (once 2m, now 7m(!)) compared to the 18 ms when doing it the manual way and b) it returns an `np.array`, I'd prefer a `DataArray`

Comment: @TomTom101: Oh, I see--I had written `np.logical_and` but I see now that xarray has its own reimplementations of some of the ufuncs.  I guess they're not compatible with NumPy, so I'll update my answer now to use the xarray version.  Please try again and I hope you'll see good performance.

Comment: Still complains: `AttributeError: '_UFuncDispatcher' object has no attribute 'reduce'`

Comment: @TomTom101: Oh well, I give up.  I just use Pandas and NumPy like everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot feed np.logical_and.reduce() with `DataArray`s, but it works nicely with pure arrays, so that's I then feed it with

```
all_maps = [fn(air_day[var], val).values for var, fn, val in comfy_warm]
```

I then add this map as a new data variable and resample it

```
air_day['nice_days'] = (['time', 'lat', 'lon'], np.logical_and.reduce(all_maps))    
air_day.nice_days.resample('M', dim='time', how='sum')
```