# Extract values from array based on multiple values conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of floats. I want to select its values based on multiple conditions:

```
import numpy as np
stamps = np.linspace(1., 100., 1e3)  
selected_stamps = stamps[((stamps > 2.)& (stamps < 10) & (stamps > 20.)& (stamps < 31) & (stamps > 80.)& (stamps < 95) )] # select only values within 2-10, 20-31, 80-95
```

How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677652/filter-data-array-on-multiple-conditions

Comment: You can use [np.all](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html?highlight=all#numpy.all)

Comment: Is the posted solution working? If so, what improvements are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use only `and` operators as you did you will get an empty collection. You have 3 ranges, so between each range you need an `or` operator:

```
selected_stamps = stamps[(
    ((stamps > 2.) & (stamps < 10)) | 
    ((stamps > 20.)& (stamps < 31)) | 
    ((stamps > 80.)& (stamps < 95)) )]
```